# Need to create a formula with Checkbox output

Tags: formula

I need to create a formula that will check a textbox if this is true: Check true where transaction date +-7 today (within the current week), transaction amount > 1,000, and picklist value = Payments.  Here is what I have:

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Type__c , "Payment") && (Total_Amount__c > 1000) && today() - Transaction_Date__c  <= 7 ,
    TRUE,
    FALSE
)
```

The checkbox is not checked when this is true so I'm missing something in my formula.  Would appreciate help with this.

Comment: `IF(<boolean expression>, true, false)` can _always_ be replaced with simply `<boolean expression>`. That's not the issue here, but less typing is generally better (because it means there's less chance to make a mistake).

Comment: Thank you Derek.

Comment: Your description of the date logic is unclear. Are you trying to check if the date transaction date is more than seven days in the past, or in the future?

Comment: Hi Adrian, I'm trying to check for these conditions:  The transaction date is within 7 days, picklist value is "Payment" and total amount is greater than $1000.  All these need to be true.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few potential issues here:

- You're checking for strictly greater than 1000 with `Total_Amount__c > 1000`. If Total_Amount__c is exactly 1000, this condition will evaluate to false (causing the entire expression to evaluate to false). This may or may not be an issue for you, just make sure your test record has a value of at least 1001.
- `today() - Transaction_Date__c  <= 7` will evaluate to true if `Transaction_Date__c` is any date in the future (because the value in that case will be a negative number). Based on your wording, you want the absolute value here to be <= 7
- A formula, on its own, cannot affect any other field. A formula field will only affect itself (it's calculated on every read, and cannot cause a trigger to fire). A Workflow/Process Builder/Flow needs you to define an action to take *after the formula evaluates to true* to actually do anything

So the first step here is to clarify whether you're working with a formula field, or a flow. A formula field is a little less work, but is a bad choice if you want to calculate a value once (or if the result shouldn't change every time the record is viewed).

The second step is to make sure that the record(s) you're testing this with avoid boundary conditions, at least to start with. Boundary conditions are things like "is 999 > 1000", things that are close to the point where the result will change. Bugs tend to live near boundary conditions, so by avoiding those situations (initially) it's easier to make sure the bulk of your logic is correct.

The third step, then, is to focus on making things right at the boundary conditions. This is usually small adjustments: changing `<` to `<=` or vice-versa, bumping numbers up or down by 1, etc...

Comment: Thank you Derek for the helpful information.